# SQL query to add a second node

Tags: mysql, sql, database, nodes, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have this code and it works.

```
SELECT distinct node, 
CASE WHEN node = 'AAA' THEN 'YYY' 
ELSE node_group END node_group,
CASE WHEN scope ='DE' ELSE scope END scope
```

However I *would like to add another node 'AAA' next to 'BBB'. How do I added to the code.

I have tried with AND and a comma but it doesn't work:

```
SELECT distinct node, 
CASE WHEN node = 'AAA' AND 'BBB' THEN 'YYY' 
ELSE node_group END node_group,
CASE WHEN scope ='DE' ELSE scope END scope
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It must be like this

```
SELECT distinct node, 
CASE WHEN node = 'AAA' OR node = 'BBB' THEN 'YYY' 
ELSE node_group END node_group,
CASE WHEN scope ='DE' THEN 1 ELSE scope END scope
```

or

```
SELECT distinct node, 
CASE WHEN node IN ('AAA', 'BBB') THEN 'YYY' 
ELSE node_group END node_group,
CASE WHEN scope ='DE' THEN 1 ELSE scope END scope
```